# What causes NPM Publish Failure, "Parse Error: Invalid major version"

Tags: npm, npm-publish

A package I maintain previously has had no issues, but just now started failing new publish attempts for a patch version update. My workflow is consistent, but now I am exiting just after the tarball details with

```sh
npm ERR! code HPE_INVALID_VERSION
npm ERR! errno HPE_INVALID_VERSION
npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@cjaas%2fcommon-components failed, reason: Parse Error: Invalid major version
```

This error is cryptic, and Google has not been helpful as of yet. The HTTP string seems odd because of the `%2f` instead of slash, though I do not know what part of the publish operation that formatting takes place. If you go to http://registry.npmjs.org/@cjaas/common-components then the URL is correct.

This message about `Invalid major version` is unclear, and I do not think it is related to the package version itself.

Any insight, leads or shared experience is much appreciated. This error has me dead in the water.

Comment: What version of `npm` are you running and what is in the "version" property in your `package.json`?

Comment: Your package has `uuip-publish` in its `npm:publish` "script" entry. `uuip-publish` does not have a repository specified or a README in npm. Downloading the tarball, it's two minified JavaScript files and nothing else. The maintainers of `uuip-publish` are not the maintainers of your package. This seems weird to me. Do you know what that package is? A Google search turns up nothing.

Comment: @Trott I'm running npm  7.13.0 at the moment. The version referenced in the package.json is the version I am bumping the common components package up to

Comment: This UUIP bit is an enterprise registry with my company, and it may have been changed somehow, that's a theory. Typically I will cd into the `/publish` directory that yarn command creates and run `npm publish` from there. not graceful, I know, but a step along the way.